# If the distant universe is expanding faster, does that mean that expansion was greater in the past, and is now slowing down?

Tags: dark-energy, cosmological-constant

The predictions of dark energy tell us that expansion is increasing. How can this be true when observations imply the opposite?
Why can't Doppler effects be attributed to the state of the Universe at the time of light emission, instead of light being 'stretched' by a pseudo space fabric that binds light to its surface?

Comment: I don't understand what this question is asking.  The whole point of the observation is that the rate of expansion was slower at the time of emission than would otherwise be predicted by a CDM without $\Lambda$ model, which is consistent with an accelerating expansion.  This doesn't contradict observations at all.

Answer (score 1):

The universe first expanded fast (faster than now) soon after the Big Bang, and slowly decelerated. At about 8 billion years after the Big Bang the dark energy became strong enough that it started accelerating the universe. Before that the universe was dominated by mass and radiation which tended to slow down the universe. Since the dark energy density does not decrease (it seems to have been the same from measurements), it's total energy increases and it causes the repulsive force that accelerates the universe and has been doing so for 5 or 6 billion years.

So, there is a history's, first inflation, then normal but decelerating 
universe, and now accelerating. We do see the history as we measure the redshifts going back in time - the further we see the further back in time we are seeing the light coming from.

See the history at https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_the_universe

You can see in the figure there that it indicates a relatively recent (a few billion years ago) accelerated expansion. It is interesting to see the various epochs, from inflation the different phases until star and galaxy formation, to now.

Answer (score 0):

The expansion of the Universe was less in the past and is now speeding up. The expansion is measured by $H=\dot{a}/a$ where $a$ is the scale factor and the dot means differentiation with respect to time. It is constant throughout the Universe at any given time. When we observe large distances we are seeing how the Universe was in the past due to the finite speed of light. This is taken into account when comparing the observations to the model predictions.